# Insert/Update whole DataTable into database table C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am facing an issue I hope to get it solved by here. I have 3 different tables in a `DataSet` and I want to insert it in the database table.

I know I can do this using `SqlBulkCopy` but there is a catch and that is I want to check if the data already exists in the database then I want it to get updated instead of insert.

And if the data doesn't exist in the database table, I want to insert it then. Any help on this would be appreciated.

I know I can iterate it through each record and then fire a procedure which will check for its existence if it exists den update or else insert. But the data size is huge and iterating through each record would be a time taking process, I don't want to use this approach.

Regards

Comment: Can't you just **(1)** bulk insert this into staging tables in SQL Server in a single run, and then **(2)** on the database side update your actual data table from the staging tables using T-SQL code on the server, which does this "if not exists then insert" logic? That would be much quicker than iterating over a large dataset locally, and inserting only some of the rows....

Comment: I dont have permission to create new tables in the DataBase.

Comment: Running read and execute commands in .NET may be inefficient for many reasons. You can generate SQL Statements like check and Insert/Update according to existence of the record. But this results in hude text file that will probable be hard to manipulate. 
You can get the Ids using simple c# application you can generate appropriate Sql commands/statements. Another option may be trying to insert all records and listen for Primary key exceptions to update them later.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Bulk Operations](http://bulk-operations.net/)

This project allows to BulkInsert, BulkUpdate, BulkDelete, and BulkMerge (Upsert).

Under the hood, it does almost what @marc_s have suggested (Use SqlBulkCopy into a temporary table and perform a merge statement to insert or update depending on the primary key).

```
var bulk = new BulkOperation(connection);
bulk.BulkMerge(dt);
```

Comment: Wow Thanks Its worth the try I guess. Lemme Check it and then upvote it if it worked perfectly :) Cheers Thanks again. BTW on the site it says its a trial so what are the limitation it consists?

Comment: Unfortunately, we have some FREE products but this one only have a PRO version (So not free). Every month a new trial version is released for the current month.

Comment: So what are the restrictions we have with the trial software?

Comment: The trial end at the end of the month and the product stop to work. You either have to purchase a License or download the new trial version to continue the evaluation.

Comment: The trial has the same features as the full version.

Comment: Oohk so we cant use it as our daily driver we have to purchase the license to evaluate that thing. Ok Got It